# How to test your USB device stack?

Tags: linux, usb

I'm developing a USB device stack for a microcontroller. "Why?" you may ask? Well first and foremost: the manufacturer's driver, which was my starting point, is complete garbage. It doesn't react to USB resets in the proper way (all endpoints should have been reinitialized), it doesn't react to setup packets in the right way (when a setup packet is received, endpoint 0 has to be reinitialized), and it doesn't allow for different descriptors depending on whether the device is running in HighSpeed or FullSpeed mode. Beside that, there was not much to do because the controller is pretty smart: endpoints are basically managed by the controller and the controller works with linked lists of DMA buffers to communicate with the application. All ACK/NACK/NYET logic is in the controller itself and it sends NACK/NYETs automatically if it runs out of DMA buffers.

But I'm getting more and more frustrated. The device is working for me (TM) but friends report that it isn't working for them. I slowly discover all that's wrong with the manufacturer's driver. All it takes is a bad USB port or cable, some missing ACKs from the host, and the USB driver/controller is in a bad state and my device doesn't respond anymore. I can think of lots of corner cases that must be taken care of, but I don't have any means of testing them. Especially missing ACKs to DATA packets sent by my device seem to be an issue.

Let's consider two scenarios:

1. My device receives a SETUP packet on endpoint 0. I respond with a DATA packet. The host does not send an ACK. Instead, the host sends another SETUP packet (the same as before).

   As far as I know, I must cancel all pending transfers on endpoint 0 (the DATA packet hasn't been ack'ed, so it's still in the queue of DMA buffers). Then I have to send the new DATA packets.
2. My device sends DATA on any endpoint (endpoint 0, bulk endpoint, whatever). The host doesn't send an ACK. Instead, a USB device reset is detected.

   I have to cancel all pending transfers on all endpoints (some packets may still be in the queue of DMA buffers). Then I wait for the usual stuff on endpoint 0 (SETUP packets etc.)

I have already run the Chapter 9 tests of the USB3CV tool. It only works on Windows. It loads some special testing xHCI driver for my USB 3 controllers and then begins testing my USB device. My device passes all the tests. The tests basically seems to download all the descriptors and then checks them for consistency. My descriptors are fixed now. All lights are green. But that's not what I am looking for.

As you can see above, thorough testing of a USB device stack can only be performed if one can control individual packets sent by the host controller. Probably, standard EHCI or xHCI controllers are not even capable of suppressing ACKs, for example.

What would be the cheapest way to thoroughly test a USB device stack? Are there special USB 2.0 host controllers? Maybe some FPGA-based solution? Of course, special software would be needed as well, to control the host controller.